# The projection on the first factor is a bijection

Tags: analysis

I require some clarification and hints on the following Problem:
\begin{align}f: X \longrightarrow Y \end{align}
The image $p$ is defined as: \begin{align} p: G_f &\longrightarrow X  \\ (x,y) &\longmapsto x\end{align}
With $G_f=\lbrace (x,y) \in X \times Y : f(x)=y \rbrace$

**Question: Is the function $p$ a bijection?**

The part I struggle the most with is that this is the first time that I deal with a 2-tuple, so please check if my approach is correct.

In the general case, to show if a function is injective choose $x,x' \in X$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$ and show that if $f(x)=f(x')$ then $x=x'$

Here is my approach to this problem: Let $(x,y) \in G_f \subset X \times Y$ and $(x',y') \in G_f \subset X \times Y$ be two 2-tuples such that $p(x,y)=x=p(x',y')$ then $(x,y)=(x',y')$ is an ordered pair, therefore $x=x'$ and $y=y'$

Is this correct?

For surjectivity, no ideas so far.

Surjectivity: $ \forall y \in Y \exists x \in X : f(x)=y $

Comment: Are you asking if $p$ is a bijection? Or if $f$ is a bijection? It doesn't seem like you've put any conditions really on $f$.

Comment: yes, I will edit this into the header. I am asking if $p$ is a bijection. I did copy the problem from my book, where they kept the statement about $f$. I thought it might have an impact on $G_f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $p(x,y)=p(x',y')$. Then $x=x'$ and hence $(x',y')=(x,y')$.

This shows that $(x,y)$ and $(x,y')$ are points on $G_f$ and by definition

$$y=f(x) , y'=f(x) \,.$$

This shows that $y=y'$.

P.S. In your proof, the part $p(x,y)=x=p(x'y')$ then $(x,y)=(x'y')$ is incomplete, that's exactly what you try to prove. $p(x,y)=x=p(x'y')$ only implies that $x=x'$, you need to also argue that $y=y'$, which is not hard.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to argument through the statement of ordered pairs, we once had to prove that $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$ I thought this might would work here as well.

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind the argument that if $(x,y)=(x',y')$ only implies that $x=x'$ but not $y=y'$?

Comment: @Spaced That's not what I said. The issue is : Why do you get that $(x,y)=(x',y')$? Note that all you know is that $p(x,y)=x=p(x',y')$, how do you conclude from here that $(x,y)=(x',y')$?

Comment: I see, I get this now, thanks for your assistance.